# How do I force gulp calls to run synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want the gulp calls below to run synchronously, one after the other. But they do not follow an order.

The [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) node module doesn't help here, as I'm not trying to run gulp tasks in series (i.e. it has syntax similar to `gulp.task("mytask", ["foo", "bar", "baz"]` etc.), but rather gulp "calls" in series, as you see below.

```
gulp.task("dostuff", function (callback) {

  gulp
    .src("...")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("...");

  gulp
    .src("...")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("...");

  gulp
    .src("...")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("...");

  callback();
});
```

How do I make them run one after the other?

Comment: You don't want to run them in series, so parallel? But that contradict the fact that you want to run them synchronously... Your last sentence also state for what I would call a serie. Can you please choose what you want?

Comment: @Aperçu As the title says, synchronously. In series.

Comment: "as I'm not trying to run tasks in series"

Comment: @Aperçu See edit above... I see why the confusion :)

Comment: Thanks, that's better :) But in your example, `gulp.task("mytask", ["foo", "bar", "baz"])`, you know the tasks does not have any specific order, it's more a parallel.

Comment: @Apercu yes that plugin uses that sort of syntax to run in series or parallel. My point is I dont want that. I want to run gulp calls in series, not entire tasks.

Comment: Okay I get it, sorry for the misunderstood

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)** as a control flow for your calls to get them in only one task, also avoiding you to get a "pyramid effect". So something like this should be good for your use-case:

```
var async = require('async');

gulp.task('yeah', function (cb) {
  async.series([
    function (next) {
      gulp.src('...')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('...')
        .on('end', next);
    },
    function (next) {
      gulp.src('...')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('...')
        .on('end', next);
    },
    function (next) {
      gulp.src('...')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('...')
        .on('end', next);
    }
  ], cb);
});
```

That will also allow you to have some error handling and target better where a problem occured.

Comment: FYI - if ".on('end', next)" doesn't work, try ".on('finish', next)".

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's just streams so you could listen for the end event (Watch out for the pyramid of doom!)

```
gulp.task("dostuff", function (callback) {

  gulp
    .src("...")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
    .on('end', function () {

      gulp
        .src("...")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
        .on('end', function () {

          gulp
            .src("...")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
            .on('end', callback);

        });
    });
});
```

But it's probably a better pattern to split it up in multiple tasks each one with a dependency on the previous one.

Comment: I need them all in one task. This code is useful if you already have them split into a number of tasks. My design doesn't work that way...

Comment: Oops, misinterpreted your question. `gulp.src()` returns a stream so you can use the `end` event I guess. I updated the answer

Comment: plusone Works, but the pyramid gets out of hand if you are composing all this dynamically at runtime. For that case, the accepted answer is better. But this works too for a simple case, as well as when you don't want to use an external library.

Comment: By all means, control flow libraries are there to structure your async code, use them. Would you mind sharing your gulpfile? I'm pretty sure there's better ways to compose your streams so you don't have to run anything in series at all.

Comment: created dynamically, that's why the pyramid was no good for my use case. In a simple/static case I would choose your way as it's easier.

Answer (score 2):

run-sequence:

> Runs a sequence of gulp tasks in the specified order. This function
>   is designed to solve the situation where you have defined run-order,
>   but choose not to or cannot use dependencies.

npm install --save-dev run-sequence

```
// runSequence will ensure this task will run the following tasks in the listed order
gulp.task('things-to-do', callback => runSequence(
    'clean-up-workspace', // clean up before copying new files
    'copy-new-files', // wait till copy-new-files done before linting
    'lint', // wait till lint is done before running minify
    'minify', // wait till minify is done before starting laundry and dinner
    ['do-laundry', // do laundry and cook dinner at the same time
    'cook-dinner'],
    'bath-cat', // don't bath the cat till both laundry and dinner are done
    callback
));
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Use [synchronous mode for glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#globsyncpattern-options)

Then return the result of gulp.src:

```
gulp.task('render', function() {
    var appJsFiles = _.map(glob.sync('src/**/*.js'), function(f) {
        return f.slice(6);
    });
    // Render the file.
    return gulp.src('src/template.html')
        .pipe(template({
            scripts: appJsFiles,
            styles: ['style1.css', 'style2.css', 'style3.css']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build_dir));
});
```

Comment: I don't understand. How does this run three gulp executions one after the other? I'm new to gulp so maybe the answer is obvious, but I don't see it...

Comment: I don't think this answers the question asked, but is exactly what I came to this page from Google looking for. Loads a list of files via glob into an array before the gulp command is run, which the gulp plugins can then consume. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like this after the last pipe

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(FINAL_DEST))
.on('end', () => gulp.src(['build']) .pipe(clean()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this ....

```
gulp.src("...")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
        .on('end', () => {
            gulp.src("...")
                .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
    
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            gulp.src("...")
                .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
    
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            gulp.src("...")
                .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
    
        })
```

but it doesn't ....
instead it wors like this ....

```
gulp.src("...")
.pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
.on('end', () => {
    gulp.src("...")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
        .on('end', () => {
            gulp.src("...")
                .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
                .on('end', () => {
                    gulp.src("...")
                        .pipe(gulp.dest("..."))
            
                })
    
        })
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.